# I have combine the results which comes from n number of threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I need to write a CSV file ,So   I  need to hit web service for more than 2k records(Each time once) ,So I am using threads to hit the webservice,

Currently I am doing like below,

```
for(String customer: Customers)
{
 Thread th=new Thread(new TaskFile(customer))
th.start();

}
**static Map=TaskFile.map
iterate map...**
}
public class TaskFile implements runnable
{

private String customer;
public static Map map=new HashMap();

public taskFile(String customer)
{
this.customer=customer;
}

 public void run()
 {
  websrivce call..
  map.put(customer,result)
}


}
```

so  I am using static map to club the results of all values but is there any other way to combine all the thread results. Since static is loaded by jvm.

I may have 100k records in future.
Ok I have my own frame work to take care of this thread which I can't share due to security issues. What about static ..This just an example. So help me on static Map and clubbing the results

Comment: Starting a thread per CSV row is definitely wrong. Use an Executor Service with a limited thread pool (no more than 10, probably).

Comment: Ok I have my own frame work to take care of this thread which I can't share due to security issues. What about static ?

Comment: How to club the all results ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer for this environment is to use a `Queue`.

Create one queue, create as many threads as you like (recommend `ThreadPools` but that's your choice) and tell each thread about the queue. Each thread then pushes items onto the queue as fas as it likes.

You then have one consumer that reads all of the results out of the queue.

```
    Queue<Type> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    for (String customer : Customers) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Producer(queue, customer));
        t.start();
    }
    Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(queue));
```

Comment: Canyou please elaborate ,Like what I need to do after the consumer thread.How it will give all the results

Comment: @Ranjithkumar - Not really - you just need many producer threads feeding data into the queue and one consumer thread pulling it out. How you indicate that all is complete is up to you, using a thread pool should help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would not want to spawn 100k threads at once - you may easily end up overwhelming the web service. Rather use a ThreadPoolExecutor to spawn the tasks, it also has methods to wait for a result. That way you can easily tune the number of concurrent requests.

If you just want to add your results to a CSV file, I would add a central [disruptor](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor) where your web service client threads are the producers and your CSV writing thread is the consumer. That way you neatly decouple hitting the web service from writing the file, minimizing latency in the process.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use a thread-safe map, like [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Second, you don't need a static map, you can pass the map in the constructor to each `Runnable`:

```
public class TaskFile implements runnable
{

    private String customer;
    private Map map;

    public taskFile(String customer, Map map)
    {
        this.customer=customer;
        this.map = map;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        //  websrivce call..
        map.put(customer,result)
    }
}

// ...
Map map = new ConcurrentHashMap();
for(String customer: Customers)
{
    Thread th=new Thread(new TaskFile(customer, map))
    th.start();

}
```

Notice that I have ignored generics as you did not specify which types you use, but you should definitly use generics.

Also, as @Marko Topolnik said, starting a thread for each row is an overkill.

Comment: agreed .Let me try this buddy

Comment: Collection.syncronizedMap(new Hashmap()) will it be fine since already I have used this

Comment: It is easier to program with ConcurrentHashMap, as you don't need to wrap its usage with *synchronized* block.

Comment: I nee dto club the values from my main class where I am running the thread not inside the runnable class.

Comment: so how can i get the output of the MAP

Comment: The part after the comment can be should be in the class that starts the runnables, not in the runnables.

Comment: for(String customer: Customers)
{
    Thread th=new Thread(new TaskFile(customer, map))
    th.start();

} after this how can I get the map which shared acorss the thread

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are creating one thread for each customer record, which will probably do something bad to your system (for reference, try looking at task manager to see how many threads other processes like to use)

My approach here would be to add the customer records to some form of (concurrent!) Queue object, and then create a handful of Runnable objects whose task is to pull from this queue as fast as they can, processing records, looping until the queue is empty, at which point they terminate.

I'm not sure whether this approach would have much performance benefit over simply handling the records single-threaded, but it is a much more sane way of doing multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

- I think your concern is if the application is deployed and there are more than one requests, your static map doesn't seem applicable (as both jobs results will be put in the same static map!).
- In this case I would suggest creating a hashmap for each job and pass it along the constructor of thread. You can remove the static within thread for the map, thereby making all threads for a job refer a single map on whom you store the results.

  ```
  Map<> map = new HashMap<>();
  for(String customer: Customers)
  {
      Thread th=new Thread(new TaskFile(customer,map ));
      th.start();
  }
  ```

- Iterate over map upon completion, as the reference is retained and results are accessible.

But, as mentioned by others, there are lots of possible leaks in your approach! Do keep an eye out.